# Localstack: awscli works, aws-sdk raise errors

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby, localstack

I want to use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) with ruby `aws-sdk`. It seems the aws sdk miss some configuration or has a bug, it raises error:

After a

```
Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('mybucket').exists?
```

it raises a:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': unable to connect to 
`mybucket.localstack`; SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
(Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)
```

On the same container, if I use `awscli` no problem at all:

```
root@35afc611394b:/app/user# aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 mb s3://test1
  make_bucket: test1
root@35afc611394b:/app/user# aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 ls
  2006-02-03 16:45:09 test1
```

I created a docker-compose.yml to help following the problem:

https://github.com/ook/localstack-s3-problem

I noticed in the readme what I tried for now.

Please advice :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for providing the detailed repo to reproduce your issue.
I was able to resolve this by forcing Aws configuration to `force_path_style` ([based off of this](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/43)).
TLDR:

> If you enable path style access on your client, it will not append the
>   bucket name to your domain name

So the config ended up looking like this:

```
Aws.config.update(endpoint: localstack, credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('sofake', 'solie'), region: 'eu-west-1', force_path_style: true)
```

The next problem was due to the fact that the bucket didn't exist yet (at least on my machine). So, I had to run this command once [`Aws::S3::Resource.new.create_bucket(bucket: 'mybucket')`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Resource.html#create_bucket-instance_method)

After that your script worked as expected:

```
   Setting endpoint to http://localstack:4572/
   Aws.config={:endpoint=>"http://localstack:4572/", :credentials=>#
   <Aws::Credentials access_key_id="sofake">, :region=>"eu-west-1", 
:force_path_style=>true}
   sleeping 1s
   setting aws endpoint
   Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('mybucket').exists?
   #<Aws::S3::Bucket:0x00559716b95a20 @name="mybucket", @data=nil, @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>>
   true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving that problem! I passed so much time on this… I'll suggest localstack to add it to a FAQ and aws-ruby-sdk to be consistent with awscli. Again: thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! :)